# onchange function not working as espected ajax

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I'm kinda new to ajax+php.
I have a select input that populates another select according to its value.

this is the html:

```
    <tr>
    <td><label>Categoría: </label></td>
    <td><select id="cmbCategorias" onchange="cmbTareas(document.getElementById('cmbCategorias').value);">
            <?php 
            require_once('dataaccess.php');
            $categorias = new legajos();
            $categorias->cmbCategorias();
            ?>
    </td>
    <td><label>Tarea: </label></td>
    <td><div id="divTareas"></div></td>
    </tr>
```

this is my javascript function:

```
    function cmbTareas(categoria_id) {
    document.getElementById("loadingimage").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("divTareas").innerHTML = "";

    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("divTareas").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById("loadingimage").style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "legajos_tareas.php?categoria_id="+categoria_id, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

legajos_tareas.php

```
    require_once('dataaccess.php');
    $categoria_id=$_GET['categoria_id'];
    $tareas = new legajos();
    $tareas->cmbTareas($categoria_id);
```

dataaccess.php

```
    public function cmbTareas($categoria_id) {
    $con = $this->conectarDB();
    $query = "CALL SPR_TAREAS(".$categoria_id.")";
    $result = $this->con->query($query);

    echo '<select id="cmbTareas">';

    while ($row = $this->con->fetch($result)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['ID'].'">'.$row['NOMBRE'].'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    $this->con->close();
    }
```

It works perfect ONLY the first time. Then if I choose another item in the select list, nothing happens. I get this error in Chrome: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function. onchange

Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are using the same name cmbTareas...try changing one of those names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either change the cmbTareas JS function name or the cmbTareas select id you get back from the ajax call. Identical names will cause a conflict. It also explains why it works the first time only.